# ASP.Net MVC 3 Areas and Mixed Mode Authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-areas, mixed-mode, mixed-authentication

Is it possible to have an ASP.Net MVC Area use different authentication then the rest of the application?  The main app has to be forms authentication since it's an extranet.  I need to have an Admin section that is only accessible by internal employees.  I've done a lot of research and have found examples of how to do Mixed Mode, but I have not found anything showing how to do it with an ASP.Net MVC Area.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each area can have its own web.config where you can configure/override the kind of authentication you want.

Here's blog post about areas and multiple web.config files:
http://mstechkb.blogspot.com/2010/10/areas-in-aspnet-mvc-20.html