# MVC Forms Authentication for multiple systems

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

I don't have a lot of experience with MVC and am looking at a lot of authentication examples, which don't fit my needs.

I need to offer access to multiple systems from one MVC application. Each system manages it's own authentication and provides similar data (i.e. System X and System Y both provide a list of widgets). Further, a user can be logged into both System X and System Y and be able to view widgets from one or the other without being re-prompted for credentials.

My plan is to use a simple route {controller}/{action}/{systemName} (i.e. Widgets/Index/SystemX). The details are fuzzy but I think I need a custom AuthorizeAttribute and a SessionProvider. The SessionProvider would handle logging into a System, which returns a sessionID. This sessionID is used when I query data from each system. One of the most fuzzy details is the best way to store user info (SystemName, user, sessionId) for each System within the session. SessionState? Cookies? FormsAuthenticationTicket? Something else?

I'd love to leverage what's already in ASP.NET & MVC, but I don't need a database for users.

Any critiques or suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

If SystemX and SystemY are different areas of the same application, you could potentially be better off using the Areas functionality of ASP.NET MVC.  This allows you to partition an application into areas, which logically-related groups of controllers, views, models, etc.

- [Walkthrough: Organizing an ASP.NET MVC Application using Areas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

  > For example, a single large e-commerce application might be divided into areas that represent the storefront, product reviews, user account administration, and the purchasing system. Each area represents a separate function of the overall application.

Each area can have it's own web.config and authentication method (e.g. [ASP.Net MVC 3 Areas and Mixed Mode Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6279139/asp-net-mvc-3-areas-and-mixed-mode-authentication)) so this might help.

---

If SystemX and SystemY are essentially the same widget list functionality, but just for different clients, you might want to look at [multi-tenancy in ASP.NET MVC](http://codeofrob.com/entries/multi-tenancy-in-asp.net-mvc---why-do-we-want-it.html).

Comment: Thanks, but Areas won't work because I would want to use a single Controller to return the widgets list for SystemX & SystemY. Multi-Tenancy isn't needed because a the application won't need to be customized for customers.